# how can I get users from API by department using REACT and REDUX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

How can I get the users by deparment from API using React and Redux.

I have got the list of users from API using the AXIOS :

```
import axios from "axios";
const DEPARTMENTS_GOT_FROM_REST_API = "http://localhost:8082/api/departments";
class AdminSetvice {
    get_all_departments() {
        return axios.get(DEPARTMENTS_GOT_FROM_REST_API)
    }
    get_users_by_depName(depName) {
        return axios.get(DEPARTMENTS_GOT_FROM_REST_API + "/" + depName)
    }
}
export default new AdminSetvice();
```

For Redux I created

**UsersByDep.ActionTypes.js**

```
export default {
    GETTING_USERS_BY_DEPARTMENT: 'GETTING_USERS_BY_DEPARTMENT',
    GET_USERS_BY_DEPARTMENT: 'GET_USERS_BY_DEPARTMENT',
    GET_USERS_BY_DEPARTMENT_ERROR: 'GET_USERS_BY_DEPARTMENT_ERROR',
}
```

**UsersByDep.actions.js**

```
import UsersByDepActionTypes from "./UsersByDep.ActionTypes"

const GettingUsersByDepName = () => ({
    type: UsersByDepActionTypes.GETTING_USERS_BY_DEPARTMENT,
})

const GetUsersByDepName = (users) => ({
    type: UsersByDepActionTypes.GET_USERS_BY_DEPARTMENT,
    payload: users
})
const GettingUsersByDepNameError = (errorMsg) => ({
    type: UsersByDepActionTypes.GET_USERS_BY_DEPARTMENT_ERROR,
    payload: errorMsg,
})



export default {

    GettingUsersByDepName,
    GetUsersByDepName,
    GettingUsersByDepNameError,
}
```

**UsersByDep.InitialState.js**

```
export default {
    usersIsLoading: false,
    users: [],
    usersErrorMessage: null,
}
```

**UsersByDep.Reducer.js**

```
import UsersByDepActionTypes from "./UsersByDep.ActionTypes";
import UsersByDepInitialState from "./UsersByDep.InitialState";


const UsersByDepReducer = (state = UsersByDepInitialState, { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case UsersByDepActionTypes.GETTING_USERS_BY_DEPARTMENT:
            return {
                ...state,
                usersIsLoading: true,
            }

        case UsersByDepActionTypes.GET_USERS_BY_DEPARTMENT:
            return {
                ...state,
                usersIsLoading: false,
                users: payload,
            }
        case UsersByDepActionTypes.GET_USERS_BY_DEPARTMENT_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                usersIsLoading: false,
                usersErrorMsg: payload,
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
};

export default UsersByDepReducer;
```

and **UsersByDep.Thunk.js**

```
import UsersByDepService from '../../../Services/Adminservice'
import UsersByDepActions from './UsersByDep.actions'

export const AsyncGetUsersByDepName = (department) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(UsersByDepActions.GettingUsersByDepName)
    UsersByDepService.get_users_by_depName(department.department)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch(UsersByDepActions.GetUsersByDepName(res.data))
            console.log(`users : ${res.data}`)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(UsersByDepActions.GettingUsersByDepNameError(err.message))
        })
}
```

I configured store, reducers and so on...other components work fine.

For the UI I created a small table for displaying the departments and users in that department:

```
import { AsyncDepartmentsLoad, AsyncDepartmentsAdd, AsyncDeleteDepartmet } from '../../Redux/Reducer/Departments/Departments.Thunk';
import { AsyncGetUsersByDepName } from '../../Redux/Reducer/Departments/UsersByDep.Thunk'

const AdminComponent = () => {
    let countriesCount = 1;
    let departmentsCount = 1;
    let locationsCount = 1;
    let plantsCount = 1;
    let UsersCount = 0;


const DepDispatch = useDispatch();
    const { depIsLoading, departments, depErrorMessage } = useSelector((state) => state.departments)
    useEffect(() => {
        DepDispatch(AsyncDepartmentsLoad())
    }, [DepDispatch]);

    const [depName, setDepName] = useState('');
    const handleDepSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const dep = {
            department: depName,
        }
        DepDispatch(AsyncDepartmentsAdd(dep))
        setDepName('');
        setDepartmentShow(false);
    }

<div className='col-6   p-2'>
                            <h3 className='text-center'>
                                <span>
                                    Departments
                                </span>
                                <span className='ms-3'>
                                    <button type='button' className='btn btn-sm btn-secondary' data-toggle="modal" onClick={() => setDepartmentShow(true)} data-target="#addNewItemModal">
                                        +
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                            </h3>
                            <div className='p-2' style={{ minHeight: "400px" }}>
                                <MDBTable hover>
                                    <MDBTableHead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th scope='col'>#</th>
                                            <th scope='col'>Department name</th>
                                            <th scope='col'></th>
                                            <th scope='col'></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </MDBTableHead>
                                    <MDBTableBody>

                                        {isLoading && <p className='text-muted bold'>loading....</p>}
                                        {errorMessage && <p className='p-3 mb-2 bg-danger text-white"'>{errorMessage}</p>}
                                        {departments && departments.map(dep =>
                                            <tr key={dep.id}>

                                                <th scope='col'>{departmentsCount++}</th>
                                                <th scope='col'>{dep.department}
                                                </th>
                                                <th><span>

                                                    {
                                                      
                                                    }

                                                </span></th>
                                                <th scope='col'> <Button variant="danger btn-sm" onClick={() => { DepDispatch(AsyncDeleteDepartmet(dep)) }}>-</Button></th>

                                            </tr>
                                        )}

                                    </MDBTableBody>
                                </MDBTable>

                            </div>
                        </div>
 </div >
                </div >
            </div >
        </>
    )
}

export default AdminComponent
```

**Itried to add**

```
<tr key={dep.id}>
    <th scope='col'>{departmentsCount++}</th>
    <th scope='col'>{dep.department}</th>
    <th><span>
         {
             () => { return DepDispatch(AsyncGetUsersByDepName(dep.department)) } 
         }
    </span></th>
    <th scope='col'> <Button variant="danger btn-sm" onClick={() => {DepDispatch(AsyncDeleteDepartmet(dep)) }}>-</Button></th>
</tr>
```

but No result.

If I access the link from Axios, for example :

```
http://localhost:8082/api/departments/IT
```

I can see the user json which in this Department :

```
[{
"firstname":"Artiom",
"lastname":"userIT",
"login":"userIT",
"email":"user.IT@mail.com",
"isActive":"ACTIVE",
"activity":true,
"password":"admin",
"secret":"admin",
"roles":"ROLE_ADMIN",
"permissions":"IT",
"creationDate":"2023-06-0210:03:33",
"departmentName":"IT",
"plant":"Plant1",
"id":1,
"permissionsList":["ROLE_ADMIN"],
"roleList":["ROLE_ADMIN"]
}]
```

How can I display at least names of users by departmetn? What I do wrong?

Comment: All the redux code you shared is related to users, but the state you are selecting in the `AdminComponent` component is related to departments. I guess you would select the users state similar to how the departments state was selected. Or I've completely misunderstood what your post is about and need clarification on what the actual issue is that you face.

Comment: I shared the code I had a problem with. In `AdminComponent` I have Departments and Countries..... and many others....this would be a long issue... I can display and perform actions with all the entities I have in `AdminComponent`. But the problem is that I can't display the users that should be selected by department. I either get an error or nothing is displayed.... This is what my question is. I edited the question like this, and added the get all departments in `AdminComponent`

Comment: I see. Are you basically asking for where to dispatch the `AsyncGetUsersByDepName` action so the user data is fetched?

Comment: I am asking how can I correctly make the request to dispatch the AsyncGetUsersByDepName action so the user data is fetched and displayed? I am new in Redux and I am trying to understand it.

Comment: I would say normally you'd dispatch it as an intentional side-effect, e.g. a `useEffect` hook, or as an asynchronous action, e.g. clicking a button, etc. When do you need to fetch users by department? Based on the location in the `departments.map` callback it appears to be the latter.

Comment: I dont need the users called as an asynchronous action. I need them to be displayed together with page.

Comment: Like I asked, when do you need to fetch users by department? And I guess where are you trying/needing to render the data once it's all fetched and updated into the redux store?

Comment: Yes, Mr., I need them once it's all fetched and updated into the redux store.